# Return Errors in API generated from OpenApi Generator 3.0 for Spring Web Flux

Tags: java, spring, spring-webflux, openapi, openapi-generator

I'm currently trying to generate a Spring Webflux Server Project using OpenApi Generator/ the openapi-generator maven plugin. I have the following OpenApi Spec:

```yaml
openapi: 3.0.3
info: #...
servers: #...
paths:
  /foo/{id}:
    get:
      tags:
        - foo
      operationId: getFoo
      summary: ...
      parameters:
        - in: path
          name: id
          schema:
            type: string
            nullable: false
            description: Foo's id.
          allowEmptyValue: false
          required: true
      responses:
        200:
          description: Foo, if foo was found.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/Foo'
        default:
          description: There was an error.
          content:
            application/json:
              schema:
                $ref: '#/components/schemas/ApiError'
components:
  schemas:
    ApiError:
      type: object
      properties:
        message:
          type: string
        code:
          type: number
        requestId:
          type: string
      required:
        - message
        - code
    Foo:
      type: object
      properties:
        bar:
          type: string
```

Essentially I want my `/foo/{id}` endpoint to return a `Foo` if it was found by the id, otherwise an `ApiError`.

Now the generator creates the following interface (edited for brevity):

```java
@Validated
@Api(value = "Foo", description = "the foo API")
public interface FooApi {
 
  @ApiOperation(
      response = Foo.class,
      tags = {
        "foo",
      })
  @ApiResponses(
      value = {
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "...", response = Foo.class),
        @ApiResponse(code = 200, message = "...", response = ApiError.class)
      })
  @GetMapping(
      value = "/foo/{id}",
      produces = {"application/json"})
  Mono<ResponseEntity<Foo>> getFoo(
      @ApiParam(value = "", required = true) @PathVariable("id") String id,
      @ApiIgnore final ServerWebExchange exchange);
}
```

How would I now go on implementing the error path of `getFoo`? Currently I have something like this:

```java
Mono<ResponseEntity<Foo>> getFoo(String id, ServerWebExchange exchange) {
  return fooDomainObjectSvc.get(id)
    .map(domainObject -> ResponseEntity.ok(createFooFromDomainObject(domainObject)))
    //This doesn't compile because ApiError doesn't inherit from Throwable
    .onErrorMap(e -> new ApiError());
}
```

What's the correct way to handle this case? Should I just modify `ApiError` to inherit from Throwable? Wouldn't this be overwritten once the specificiation changes and I rerun the code-generation step?

Comment: Why do you use 200 status in case of error?

Comment: I don't. I think it's auto-generated because of the "default" keyword in the spec.